# jQuery : Get content of id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

Need some help with jQuery DOM. 
I need to extract the content of the id. I have a list that user can select and it will filter the `hotspot` of the map. After user select, I want `filtertitle` to display the new selected filter. I can apply the "id" to the filter title but not sure about the content because the content has Shopping / Dining. Someone please.

HTML

```
<div class="map-filter">
    <div class="filtertitle">All Categories</div>
    <ul class="filter-list">
        <li class="active" id="All Categories">All Categories</li>
        <li id="Shopping">Shopping/Dining</li>
        <li id="Hotel">Hotels & Resorts</li>
        <li id="Art">Art Galleries</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.filter-list li').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.filtertitle').html(id); //This part is where I set the id 
});
```

Comment: `$('.filtertitle').html($(this).text());` ?

Comment: Hi Shaunak. This works perfectly. Could you explain this abit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**, it gives you the text content of the desired element.

```
$('.filtertitle').html($(this).text());
```

In case of html content use **[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**.

```
$('.filtertitle').html($(this).html());
```

Comment: Oh yes. I've decided to use .html because I noticed I can add icons to the list and then it will appear on filtertitle. Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're asking correctly then you can try something like this.

```
$('.filter-list li').click(function(e){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.filtertitle').html($(e.currentTarget).text());
});
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/583zgs57/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simple setting id, you can use $(this).text(); to fetch the text content of current element.

```
$('.filter-list li').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.filtertitle').html($(this).text()); 
});
```